# Create SELECT procedure/trigger to decrypt data on ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, encryption, database-trigger

I have this query

```
SELECT id, UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_NCHAR(DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT(password,
                                pkg_so_42979606.cipher_type(),
                                UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW('pMV3D4xhyfNxp3YyfLWzAErGcKkIjK3X6uc/WIeVTls=', 'AL32UTF8'))),
                             'AL32UTF8') password
FROM customeren;
```

I want to select this table. But i don't want to write this code again and again. What i need to do? How select data from this table in easier way? Oracle 11g XE

Comment: Depends on how you're going to use it. Are you interested in storing the result set of the query at once and then use it at multiple places? Or do you want to run the query each time with a different argument and get different results?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view with the selection criteria above and then just call your select query on the view. Not sure if Oracle syntax is the same but in SQL Server it would be

```
    CREATE VIEW myschema.SomeViewName AS
    SELECT id, UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_NCHAR(DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT(password,
                                pkg_so_42979606.cipher_type(),
                                UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW('pMV3D4xhyfNxp3YyfLWzAErGcKkIjK3X6uc/WIeVTls=', 'AL32UTF8'))),
                             'AL32UTF8') password
    FROM customeren;
```

Then you can call SELECT * FROM myschema.SomeViewName, although using wildcards is generally not a good idea because you return all columns, when you may not require them.  If you want to pass in parameters dynamically then you could consider using a function instead.